# how to create dynamic nested list view in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, dynamic

I need to create nested listview, below code is working fine, but I need **listOfTiles** as dynamic,
for ex: I am passing 'Banks', 'SocialMedia', i.e hard coded,
Below are my appropriate lists, By using those lists like _types, _names, _subtypes,, I need to create **listOfTiles**

Result will be like,
if I tap **Banks**, that will have **sbi** **hdfc**
if I tap **SociaMedia**, that will have **fb**

```
List<Type> _types = ['Banks','SociaMedia']
List<Name> _names = ['SBI','HDFC','FB']
List<SubType> _subtypes = ['Net Banking','Debit card']
```

````
body: new ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return new StuffInTiles(listOfTiles[index]);
          },
          itemCount: listOfTiles.length,
        )

class StuffInTiles extends StatelessWidget {
  final MyTile myTile;

  StuffInTiles(this.myTile);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildTiles(myTile);
  }

  Widget _buildTiles(MyTile t) {
    if (t.children.isEmpty)
      return new ListTile(
          onTap: () => print("tap"),
          subtitle: new Text("Subtitle"),
          selected: false,
          title: new Text(t.title));
    return new ExpansionTile(
      key: new PageStorageKey<int>(1),
      title: new Text(t.title),
      children: t.children.map(_buildTiles).toList(),
    );
  }
}


class MyTile {
  String title;
  List<MyTile> children;
  MyTile(this.title, [this.children = const <MyTile>[]]);
}


List<MyTile> listOfTiles = <MyTile>[
  new MyTile(
    'Banks',
    <MyTile>[
      new MyTile(
        'SBI',
        <MyTile>[
          new MyTile(
            'NetBanking',
            <MyTile>[
              new MyTile('username'),
              new MyTile('password'),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
  new MyTile(
    'SocialMedia',
    <MyTile>[
      new MyTile('Gmail'),
      new MyTile('Facebook'),
      new MyTile('Twitter'),
    ],
  )]```
````

Answer (score 0):

It's quite impossible to understand what you want - but let me try to help you out

I think this is what your looking for :

```
class MyTile {
  var tileName;
  MyTile({
    this.tileName,
  });
}

// Your dynamic List
var myTile = [
  MyTile(
    tileName: 'Banks',
  ),
  MyTile(
    tileName: 'SBI',
  ),
  MyTile(
    tileName: 'username',
  ),
  MyTile(
    tileName: 'password',
  ),
  MyTile(
    tileName: 'SocialMedia',
  ),
  MyTile(
    tileName: 'Gmail',
  ),
  MyTile(
    tileName: 'Facebook',
  ),
];
```

Comment: Share me a picture of what you'd like it to look like

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_2bqBIBYwPRZcPTzgU27N3dq_b1zzG8W/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_nHWIsF2ipvHSeW3LGvOyP3jU_gPGt-B/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ltNcnRxPor358TBHvny2vryT2pxHSjTF/view?usp=sharing